# Python: Checking at least two values in a list satisfy a condition

Tags: python, list, if-statement, multiple-instances

I have a list created in Python, something like `a=[1.0,3.7,1.0,3.9]`.
I need to check a condition with `if` at least two values in the list have values in the range [3.0,4.0], then do something.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
if sum(1 for e in a if 3.0 <= e < 4.0) >= 2:
    something()
```

`1 for e in a if 3.0 <= e < 4.0` will return the iterator `(1, 1)` (i.e. a value `1` for each `e` such that it is between `3.0` and `4.0`); then summing those ones gets us the count of the elements that satisfies the condition.

> will this early exit when the list `a` is very long?

No. This will, tho, but it makes the logic a bit more complex:

```
from itertools import accumulate
if any(n for n in accumulate(1 for e in a if 3.0 <= e < 4.0) if n >= 2):
    something()
```

Comment: Wow, I didn't know you could do a boolean range change like `min <= e < max`. Awesome! Is this Python3.*?

Comment: No, it's both Python2 and Python3. However, do not try to generalise it to other languages, most don't have that bit of syntactic sugar.

Comment: @jhuang: [Python2](https://docs.python.org/3.5/reference/expressions.html#comparisons), [Python3](https://docs.python.org/2.7/reference/expressions.html#comparisons): "Comparisons can be chained arbitrarily, e.g., `x < y <= z` is equivalent to `x < y and y <= z`, except that `y` is evaluated only once (but in both cases `z` is not evaluated at all when `x < y` is found to be false)."

Comment: @Amadan will this early exit when the list `a` is very long?